読み込んでるテキストファイルの自動更新
処理が完了するとテキストファイルに1行ずつデータが書き込まれます。
そのテキストファイルを開いてる際に書き込まれると「再読み込み」のダイアログが出ると思うんですがダイアログを出さずに自動更新する設定等ってあったりしますか？

設定のプロパティの [ファイル] ページで、[外部から変更された時] ドロップ ダウン リストから [更新していなければ常に読み直す] を選択してください。

ありがとうございます。できました
